# Раздельно или вместе с НЕ

Tags: орфография

Проходила тест **Правописание НЕ с частями речи**, в словосочетании *не( )сильнее меня* думала, что пишется вместе, т. к. можно подобрать синоним *слабее,* но в ответах раздельно. Почему? Или это ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Проходила тест **Правописание НЕ с частями речи**, в словосочетании
>   *не( )сильнее меня* думала, что пишется вместе...

.

***Не/сильнее*** в русском требует раздельного написания. См. [***Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник:***](http://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B8_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/#id-4%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%C2%A7148)

> **§ 149...**
>   **От ряда прилагательных с приставкой  *не-*   и соответствующих
>   наречий формы сравнительной степени не образуются**. К ним относятся
>   образования с  ***не-***   от слов, имеющих формы с суффиксом ***−е***
>   и ***−ше*** (напр., *небогатый, непростой, негромкий, нетонкий,
>   недалеко* ), с ударным суффиксом ***−ее*** (напр., *несильный,
>   неясный, несложный, невесело* ).
>
> Поэтому обычны написания *не богаче, не проще, не громче, не дальше,
>   **не сильнее**, не яснее, не веселее.*

.

Такое написание ***не сильнее*** зафиксировано и в словарях. См., к примеру,  [***Русский орфографический словарь:***](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5&all=x)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Подбор синонима — это **формальный прием**, который подтверждает, что перед нами утвердительная конструкция, например: в небольшом (маленьком) городе. В то же время в ряде случаев формальное решение не годится, так как задача решается **по смыслу**. Это означает, что, исходя из текста, мы должны определить вид конструкции: **отрицание с раздельным написанием или утверждение со слитным написанием**, например: город небольшой (маленький)  или город не большой (среднего размера). Обычно смысловое решение применяется **для сказуемого**, в том числе если оно выражено **сравнительной степенью прилагательного.**

**Общее правило**

**1) Утверждение,  частица НЕ пишется  слитно:** тропинка становилась всё **незаметнее**  (схема образования:  заметный — незаметный — незаметнее).

Что, казалось,  может быть **неинтереснее** и бесцветнее какого-нибудь плоского захолустья. С каждым годом эта дата всё **незаметнее**. Чем дальше, тем **непонятнее**.

**2) Отрицание, частица НЕ пишется раздельно:** он **не заметнее других** (схема образования:  заметный — заметнее — не заметнее).

За кулисами едва ли **не интереснее**, чем на сцене. Теперь мотивация героев становится если **не понятнее**, то более объяснимой. Лиза была **не равнодушнее**, хотя и молчаливее его.

3) **Всегда раздельно (только отрицание)**
   Всегда раздельно пишутся выражения: не ниже, не выше, не лучше,  не хуже, не ближе, не беднее.

**Решение примера**

Он **не сильнее** меня (отрицание, схема образования:  сильный — сильнее — не сильнее). Практически в текстах встречается **только отрицательная конструкция**.

А вот утвердительную конструкцию с этим словом трудно представить (например: этот мальчик несильный, а тот еще несильнее). Конечно, мы скажем: этот несильный, а тот еще слабее. Или так: этот несильный (слабый), и другой не сильнее его.

Comment: *Что, казалось...* Не хочу придираться, но разве так говорят без "бы" и не "кажется". Разве это не воспринимается просто как прошедшее время?

Comment: Вроде бы нормально. Вот еще пример: "Наука, успехи, истина, открытия ― всё, что так занимало, что, казалось, составляло смысл жизни, ― всё растаяло, рассыпалось ненужной шелухой". [Даниил Гранин. Зубр (1987)]

Comment: Так тут и есть прошедшее время (всё, что раньше занимало, теперь растаяло, рассыпалось)! А у Вас разве в нём есть смысл?

Comment: >> *Общее правило*. Это "общее правило" все равно не объясняет, почему *(не)заметнее* может писаться и слитно, и раздельно, а *не сильнее* — только раздельно.

Comment: Артем. не могу понять, что  неправильно. Есть три вводных слова: кажется, казалось, казалось бы,  они используются в разных ситуациях: настоящее время, прошедшее время и условное наклонение со значением уступки (казалось бы, так,  но на деле по-другому).

Comment: Niemand, это смысловое решение, от контекста зависит.  (1) Была тропинка незаметной,  а стала еще незаметнее.  (2) Он  вам кажется заметной фигурой,  а в действительности он не заметнее других.

Comment: Ой, Sibylla, простите! Во-первых, я не заметил, что это **пример,** а потом, действительно, в этом примере может быть и прошедшее время. :)

Answer (score 0):

Вы же чувствуете, что здесь налицо отрицание? Отрицается, что сильнее. Например: *Он сильнее тебя? — Нет, он не сильнее меня.* Поэтому и раздельно.
В подобных случаях надо прежде всего пытаться определить, есть ли отрицание.